# Different keyboard layouts with different languages 18.10

Tags: keyboard, input-language, japanese, chinese, dvorak

I want to use Dvorak for English and Qwerty for Chinese/Japanese. I can get Japanese input to work but it's still under the Dvorak layout. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which input methods are you using for Chinese respective Japanese?

Answer (score 0):

**To assign different keyboard layouts on each language.**

[image]

System settings > Text Entry, select your IME (this example Mozc), click on the screwdriver and wrench icon.

[image]

On the Input Method Configuration window, select Chinese/Japanese with the Input Method Engine, and click on the Gear/Wrench icon below (red marker), please.

[image: Mozc keyboard layout]

[image: selecting layout]

If this item is "Input Method Default" (your system default) or "Dvorak" then you get Dvorak layout.

Scroll and select "English US" then you get the QWERTY layout for Chinese/Japanese IME individually.